# Stop the Scrollmagic triggers from showing

Tags: scrollmagic

Is there a way to make all the triggers not show?

Like a class i can target with css or something i can add to the scollmagic parameters.

I'm talking about the "trigger fade scene, start fade scene  and end fade scene" markers to be exact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after looking around, I didn't find anything useful so I tried doing it using colors.

```
        .addIndicators({
        name: '',
        colorTrigger: 'transparent', 
        colorStart: 'transparent',
        colorEnd: 'transparent'
    })
```

Add 'transparent' as the trigger/hook color and it wont be visible anymore